# For loop to search for occurrence of characters using parameters start & end

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm having trouble setting up a for-loop to search for the occurrences of characters a-z, A-Z, and 0-9 within a string called text. This string is from an input file. My for-loop is set up as:

```
for (char ch = start; ch <= end; ch++) {
    body
}
```

The assignment is I have to create a method named `public static void countChars(String text, char start, char end)` and within this method I have to use a for-loop to search for occurrences of three things: a-z, A-Z, and 0-9. If match is found I have to increment the counter. Then in main I have to invoke the method by calling `countChars(text, 'a', 'z')`, `countChars(text, 'A', 'Z')`, and `countChars(text, '0', '9')`;

However, I don't know how to set it up to search for the 3 different types of characters listed above. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: break down the issue to small issues for the start. re check the definition of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void  main(){
    String text = "your text"
    count1=countChars(text,'a','z');
    count2=countChars(text,'A','Z');
    count3=countChars(text,'0','9');

}


public static int countChars(String text, char start, char end){
 int  count=0;
for(char ch : text.toCharArray()){
        if (ch>=start && ch<=end)
            count++;

    }
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the library methods provided in `Character`:

```
String s = "abc!123";
for(Character ch : s.toCharArray()) {
   if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
        System.out.println(ch);
   }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I HAVE to use the parameters 'start' and 'end' in my for-loop for this assignment. char start is the first character to search for and char end is the last to search for; if a match is found I have to increment the counter.

Comment: So? You can write the above code with "start" and "end", right? Whats the problem ? `for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i); if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
// do whatever you want
   }`

Comment: You have not defined your problem clearly. If I read your comments in other answers, I believe you are looking for a program that gives you count of each alphanumeric character in a string. You should read on `HashMap` and `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for counting the characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) separately:

```
// File name:  FindCharacters.java

import java.util.*;

public class FindCharacters {

    public static void countChars(String text, char start, char end) {
        System.out.println("\n\n----------");
        int grandTotal = 0;
        HashMap<Character, Integer> characterMap = new HashMap<>();
        // Search for a-z, A-Z and 0-9
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if((c >= start && c <= end)) {
                // Increase the grand total when an interesting character is found
                grandTotal++;

                // Now, count the number of occurences of the individual character
                int count = 1;
                if (characterMap.containsKey(c)) {
                    count += (characterMap.get(c));
                }
                characterMap.put(c, count);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Grand total from " + start + " to " + end + " = " + grandTotal);
        System.out.println("Occurences of individual characters: ");
        for(char c: characterMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(c + " : " + characterMap.get(c));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the input string: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        countChars(input, 'a', 'z');
        countChars(input, 'A', 'Z');
        countChars(input, '0', '9');
    }   
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac FindCharacters.java

> java FindCharacters
Enter the input string: 
This is a sentence                                                                  


----------
Grand total from a to z = 14
Occurences of individual characters:
a : 1
s : 3
c : 1
t : 1
e : 3
h : 1
i : 2
n : 2


----------
Grand total from A to Z = 1
Occurences of individual characters:
T : 1


----------
Grand total from 0 to 9 = 0
Occurences of individual characters:
```

---

**Beginners approach, using arrays and no HashMap:**

**Here is a variation of the above example, without using HashMap:**

```
// File name:  FindCharactersBeginnersApproach.java

import java.util.*;

public class FindCharactersBeginnersApproach {

    public static void countChars(String text, char start, char end) {
        System.out.println("\n\n----------");
        char letters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
                            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 
                            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 
                            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
                            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 
                            'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 
                            'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 
                            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
                            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

        int count[] = new int[62];
        for(int i = 0; i < 62; i++) {
            count[i] = 0;
        }

        int grandTotal = 0;

        // Search for a-z, A-Z and 0-9
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if((c >= start && c <= end)) {
                // Increase the grand total when an interesting character is found
                grandTotal++;

                // Now, count the number of occurences of the individual character
                for (int j = 0; j < 62; j++) {
                    if(c == letters[j]) {
                        count[j] = (count[j] + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Grand total from " + start + " to " + end + " = " + grandTotal);
        System.out.println("Occurrences of individual characters: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 62; i++) {
            if(count[i] > 0) {
                System.out.println(letters[i] + " : " + count[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the input string: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        countChars(input, 'a', 'z');
        countChars(input, 'A', 'Z');
        countChars(input, '0', '9');
    }   
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac FindCharactersBeginnersApproach.java

> java FindCharactersBeginnersApproach
Enter the input string: 
This is a sentence


----------
Grand total from a to z = 14
Occurrences of individual characters:
a : 1
c : 1
e : 3
h : 1
i : 2
n : 2
s : 3
t : 1


----------
Grand total from A to Z = 1
Occurrences of individual characters:
T : 1


----------
Grand total from 0 to 9 = 0
Occurrences of individual characters:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your example, however I have to list out the number of occurrences for each letter/digit. For instance if the input was: "This is a sentence" then the output would be a: 1 c:1 e: 3 h: 1 i: 2 n: 2 s: 3 t: 1. How would I do this?

Comment: Hi Flexico, I updated the program to use a HashMap to cuont the number of occurrences of each character.

Comment: is there a way you can explain this without usage of HashMap as I haven't learned that yet? It's an intro class to Java haha. Also, I need the characters in alphabetical order, how would I make this change? Thank you so so much for your help!

Comment: Hi Flexico, I added a variation that uses plain arrays and no HashMap.

Comment: Hi Gopinath, thank you so much for your time & effort in providing me with examples/solutions. I'll look further into HashMaps as I realize it's very useful.